# Why I can't get scope property value defined in link?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this directive:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("siteObjects").directive("siteObjectsList", [newObjectsLits]);

    function newObjectsLits() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                objects: "=",
                region: "=",
                contractid: "=",
                //isannual:"="
            },
            link: function (scope) {
                scope.name = 'Jeff';
            },
            templateUrl: "app/siteObjects/templates/siteObjectsListDirective.tmpl.html",
            controller: "siteObjectsListController",
            controllerAs: "list"
        }
        return directive;
    }
})();
```

Controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
angular.module("siteObjects").controller("siteObjectsListController", ["$scope","config","toaster",
  siteObjectsListController]);

function siteObjectsListController($scope,
                                   config, toaster
                                   ) {


    $scope.test = function (shRev,index) {
        var dx = index;
        var is = shRev;
    }

    function getPhotoUrl(item) {
        return config.baseUrl + "api/siteobjects/" + $scope.region.Id + "/photo/" + item.Id;
    }

    function zoomSiteObject(object) {
        siteObjectsService.zoomObject(object);
    }
}
})();
```

In directive defenition I have link:

```
link: function (scope) { scope.name = 'Jeff';}
```

when I try to access in controller to name property from link, like that:

```
var myName = $scope.name;
```

myName  is undefined.

Any idea why I can't get $scope.name property value?

Comment: This is because, you have isolated scope in directive

Comment: @Ved, can I pass name = 'Jeff' using resolve in custom directive?